# When I subdivide a face, how do I get each face from the result in Python?

Tags: python, add-on, faces, subdivision-surface

For example, if I subdivided a square face so there were now 4 faces, how I do iterate through those 4 faces in a Blender add-on?

Comment: Could you elaborate on the question. Do you mean : you want to map the newly created faces on the old face, which was subdivided? If yes, I don't think that kind of history would be maintained in any of the built-in objects. If you simply want to iterate through the faces, you can do that through bmesh.faces iterator. Here, you won't get the face that was subdivided but the new 4 faces that were the result of the subdivision.

Comment: @BlenderDadaist I would like the second option; I simply want to iterate through the new faces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code to iterate through the faces of the selected object:

```
import bmesh
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.object
me = obj.data

if me.is_editmode:
    bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
else:
    bm = bmesh.new()
    bm.from_mesh(me)

for face in bm.faces:
    #Your logic here
    print(face.index)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Bmesh approach**

Using the bmesh operator [`bmesh.ops.subdivide_edges(..)`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bmesh.ops.html#bmesh.ops.subdivide_edges) with `cuts = 1` and `use_grid_fill = True` will produce the result of subdividing a quad face into four.

Test script, run in edit mode, subdivides face 0, prints the four newly added faces.

```
import bpy
import bmesh
context = bpy.context
ob = context.edit_object
me = ob.data

bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

face = bm.faces[0]
ret = bmesh.ops.subdivide_edges(bm, edges=face.edges[:], cuts=1)
for f in ret['geom']:
    # new geometry
    if isinstance(f, bmesh.types.BMFace):
        print(f)
```