# How to determine whether my bm.select_history.active is a BMVert, BMFace or a BMEdge?

Tags: python, bmesh

I am trying to write a conditional statement for my script. If the user has one Active Edge Selected, then the script will run. Otherwise it won't.

I know that if I have an active edge, then bm.select_history_active will print something like , index = ... etc). Otherwise it would print either BMFace or BMVert (correct me if I'm wrong).

So how can I check whether the bm.select_history_active is a BMEdge? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Python's `isinstance`**

The method `isinstance(ob, type)`  will return `True` if the object `ob` is an instance of type `type`

Example [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/120242/when-i-subdivide-a-face-how-do-i-get-each-face-from-the-result-in-python/120244#120244)

```
is_edge = isinstance(bm.select_history.active, bmesh.types.BMEdge)
```

Answer (score 1):

`bm.select_history.active` actually gives you the *object* of type of the selected element of the mesh. So actually, `type(bm.select_history.active).__name__` will give you the strings 'BMEdge', 'BMVert', 'BMFace' etc. based on the type of selection. You can use this in the condition, which could be something like:

```
activElem = bm.select_history.active
if (activElem != None and type(activElem).__name__ == 'BMEdge'):
    #The logic to process the edge (activElem.index etc.)
```

There may be a better way to do this. So maybe, you can wait for a while for a better answer :)

Comment: Thanks! I used the other solution in this case.

Comment: Yes, that one is better. String comparison is not good for checking the object type.